# How to draw such kind of shape in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do i achive such type of shape in latex

[image]

Comment: Well, this is pretty easy with `tikz` (or even `picture` environment) -- even with my limited knowledge of Tikz I would get this with a simple `\draw` statement. There are one billion examples in the TikZ manual about such things -- have you read it?

Comment: How can we repeat such figure say 4 @ChristianHupfer

Comment: You haven't understood what I wrote and tried to say in my comment above, apparently. :-(  The downvote isn't by me, however

Comment: I have voted all the users. +1 You are excellent users.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As simple as it can get:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw [thick] (0,0) -| (1,3) -| (0.7,0.5) -| cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

A very customizable version (just for fun).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\lshape}{O{}}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { teron/lshape } { #1 }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_teron_lshape_box
   {
    \driver_draw_begin:
    \driver_draw_join_round:
    \driver_draw_linewidth:n { \l_teron_lshape_linewidth_dim }
    \driver_draw_moveto:nn { 0pt } { 0pt }
    \driver_draw_lineto:nn { \l_teron_lshape_base_dim } { 0pt }
    \driver_draw_lineto:nn
     { \l_teron_lshape_base_dim }
     { \l_teron_lshape_height_dim }
   \driver_draw_lineto:nn
     { \l_teron_lshape_base_dim - \l_teron_lshape_vertwidth_dim }
     { \l_teron_lshape_height_dim }
   \driver_draw_lineto:nn
     { \l_teron_lshape_base_dim - \l_teron_lshape_vertwidth_dim }
     { \l_teron_lshape_horwidth_dim }
   \driver_draw_lineto:nn
     { 0pt }
     { \l_teron_lshape_horwidth_dim }
   \driver_draw_closestroke:
  }
  \box_set_wd:Nn \l_teron_lshape_box { \l_teron_lshape_base_dim }
  \box_set_ht:Nn \l_teron_lshape_box { \l_teron_lshape_height_dim }
  \leavevmode\box_use:N \l_teron_lshape_box
  \group_end:
 }

\box_new:N \l_teron_lshape_box
\keys_define:nn { teron/lshape }
 {
  base      .dim_set:N = \l_teron_lshape_base_dim,
  height    .dim_set:N = \l_teron_lshape_height_dim,
  hwidth    .dim_set:N = \l_teron_lshape_horwidth_dim,
  vwidth    .dim_set:N = \l_teron_lshape_vertwidth_dim,
  thickness .dim_set:N = \l_teron_lshape_linewidth_dim,
  base      .initial:n = 2cm,
  height    .initial:n = 5cm,
  hwidth    .initial:n = 1cm,
  vwidth    .initial:n = 0.5cm,
  thickness .initial:n = 0.4pt,
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\lshape\qquad
\lshape[thickness=0.8pt]\qquad
\lshape[base=2cm,height=2cm,hwidth=1cm,vwidth=0.3cm,thickness=1pt]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just for the fun, the same picture with MetaPost (LuaLaTeX document). Almost a copy-paste of a `tikz` coding. (Well, in all fairness the tikz path syntax has been strongly inspired by MetaPost… ;-))

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85, luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    draw (origin -- (1,0) -- (1, 3) -- (0.7, 3) --  (0.7,0.5) -- (0, 0.5) -- cycle)
        scaled cm;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can do that with very simple tools (`tabular`, `\cline`, `\hline` and the `boldline` package from the `shipunov` bundle, to have lines with custom thickness), or with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array, boldline}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[b]{p{5mm}@{\,}V{2}c@{\,}V{2}}
\clineB{2-2}{2}
 & \rule{0pt}{25mm}\\
 \clineB{1-1}{2}
 \multicolumn{2}{V{2}c V{2}}{} \\
\hlineB{2}
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{pspicture}
\pnodes{A}(0,0)(1.1,0)(1.1,3)(0.8,3)(0.8,0.4)(0,0.4)
  \pspolygon[linejoin = 1](A0)(A1)(A2)(A3)(A4)(A5)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do you like?

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(0.36,0.52) rectangle (3.96,5.22);
\draw [line width=2.pt] (1.,2.)-- (2.,2.);
\draw [line width=2.pt] (2.,2.)-- (2.,5.);
\draw [line width=2.pt] (2.,5.)-- (3.,5.);
\draw [line width=2.pt] (3.,5.)-- (3.,1.);
\draw [line width=2.pt] (3.,1.)-- (1.,1.);
\draw [line width=2.pt] (1.,1.)-- (1.,2.);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```